# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReadLine')

Tags: node.js, readline, node-serialport, undefined-function

When launching the app.js, there is an error written above, here is an example of the code

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.ReadLine;
const port = new SerialPort('COM4', { baudRate: 9600 });
const parser = new Readline();

// Открытие COM порта и установка связи
port.open(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Ошибка открытия порта: ', err.message);
  }
  
  console.log('Порт открыт');
});

// Парсинг принятых данных
port.pipe(parser);
parser.on('data', function(data) {
  // Обработка полученных данных
  console.log('Получены данные: ', data);
});

// Управление сервоприводом
function controlServo(servoNumber, angle) {
  const command = `${servoNumber},${angle}`;
  port.write(command, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Ошибка записи: ', err.message);
    }
    
    console.log('Отправлена команда: ', command);
  });
}
```

Why does the code not run, but gives an error? I sat on most of the forums and did not find an answer. I have fully checked the instructions for using the SerialPort library and the ReadLine usage instructions

```
// Пример использования
controlServo(1, 90); // Управление сервоприводом 1: угол 90 градусов
```

I tried to load the ReadLine module directly, but eventually an error appeared in the console that serialport is not a constructor

There is also a site code from which data should be transmitted to the COM port

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Управление сервоприводами</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Управление сервоприводами</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="servo1">Сервопривод 1:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="servo1" placeholder="Угол">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="servo2">Сервопривод 2:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="servo2" placeholder="Угол">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="servo3">Сервопривод 3:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="servo3" placeholder="Угол">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="servo4">Сервопривод 4:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="servo4" placeholder="Угол">
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="recordActions()">Запись</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="playbackActions()">Воспроизведение</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="clearActions()">Очистка</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    function recordActions() {
      // Код для отправки команды записи на COM порт
      // Используйте значения из полей ввода для углов сервоприводов
    }
    
    function playbackActions() {
      // Код для отправки команды воспроизведения на COM порт
    }
    
    function clearActions() {
      // Код для отправки команды очистки на COM порт
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the error code that the console outputs:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReadLine')
    at <anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8/Desktop/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(7)/app.js:2:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
```

Comment: I think you might be using older code as an example. Have you looked at the ReadLine here?

https://serialport.io/docs/api-parser-readline